# Case When Statement in Google Data Studio not working

Tags: case, looker-studio

I'm trying to create a `CASE WHEN` statement in Google Data Studio. However, it not applying to my table. I tried a few combinations and nothing seems to work. It also says that the syntax is valid.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved using the 3 [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below:

### 1) Metric (`Needs Intervention`)

```sql
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN Absenteeism Avg in Days > 15 THEN "Needs Intervention"
    ELSE NULL END)
```

### 2) Metric (`Stable`)

```sql
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN Absenteeism Avg in Days <= 15 THEN "Stable"
    ELSE NULL END)
```

### 3) Dimension (`Needs Intervention` / `Stable`)

```
CASE
  WHEN Absenteeism Avg in Days > 15 THEN "Needs Intervention"
  ELSE "Stable"
END
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/30912349-a714-4a6f-a234-116911f7714f/page/vrYfB) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]